# Laravel Unique Depends on Other Column

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a table school_name and in form i want to apply 2 conditions if school name exist than branch must be unique

I tried below validation but its not working

```
 'name' => 'required',
 'branch' => 'required:unique:school_name,name',
```

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-check-for-unique-column-combanation-from-the-validation-rule might be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Rule::unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique) to achieve your validation rule

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

$schoolname = "abc";
$branch = "new";

Validator::make($data, [
    'branch' => [
        'required',
         Rule::unique('tablename')->where(function ($query) use($schoolname ,$branch) {
           return $query->where('school_name', $schoolname)->where('branch', $branch);
         });
    ],
]);
```